# Deriving an equation to describe unraveling system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, angular-velocity

The following is my derivation of an equation that describes the unrolling of a spool of chained beads.  Note that these beads are very small in diameter and no layering is done so that change in radius of the system is negligible (please read to the end):

[image: First part of the derivation]

[image: Second part of the derivation]

[image: Third part of the derivation]

I am attempting to create a formula that can predict how long it will take a spool of chained beads to unravel given some initial conditions.  So far I've only been able to derive a formula that gives the instantaneous rate of change of angular velocity (angular acceleration).  Since all those variables are time-dependent, my goal to create a formula that gives me the angular acceleration at some point in time.

I have two ideas on how to do this:

1. I am planning to conduct experiments, and with the use of some tracking software, measure these variables (torque, the radius of the system, angular velocity etc.), plug them into the equation, and plot the value for angular acceleration at that point in time.  This graph will show the angular acceleration as a function of time, which can be integrated twice to get the angle as a function of time and thus displacement (amount of roll that has unwound).  A problem that arises is that those variables will disappear.  The trend line will be some polynomial that depends on time.
2. Since this is basically a differential equation, I could plug this into a slope field plotter as a method of integration.

**Question: How should I go about deriving an equation that will tell me how long it will take for the spool to unravel based on initial conditions.**

P.S. is my equation correct so far?